# How to get data in iWatch extension from parent app?

Tags: ios, widget, nsuserdefaults

In parent app:

```
NSUserDefaults *myDefaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc]
                              initWithSuiteName:@"group.soft.iWatch"];
[myDefaults setObject:@"ABC" forKey:@"baseCountry"];
[myDefaults synchronize];
```

In iWatch :

```
NSUserDefaults *myDefaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc]
                              initWithSuiteName:@"group.soft.iWatch"];
NSLog(@"%@",[myDefaults objectForKey:@"baseCountry"]);
```

In application target, group is also checkmarked.
This way is work very well for Widget extension.